# Salesforce: Checkbox that evaluates Lead field against text list

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I have a large list of company names (comp_list).

On every Lead, I want a checkbox field that evaluates to true if the Lead's Company value is contained in comp_list.

The character count for the full list is over 10k which means I can't store it as a long text field on every Lead record.

I believe I can come to a basic solution using multiple formula fields across the list but I'd prefer something neater and would be ideal to have something that works for 50k+ characters so I can make the lookup a bit more sophisticated.

Any thoughts or suggestions appreciated - preferably without Apex, but will accept Apex answers if nothing else works.

Thanks,
Pieter

Answer (score 0):

You can try if the below solution works.

1. Create a custom settings object with type as **Hierarchy**
2. Create a new Long text area field on the above object(Which will store more
   than 10k characters)
3. Set the value of this long text area to your list of company names
4. Now you can create a formula field on lead and access this custom setting in formula field using {!$Setup.CustomSettingName__c.CustomFieldName__c}

Let me know if it helps

Comment: Thanks. Never used Custom Settings before and like the approach. Unfortunately, it doesn't look like they give the option of creating a Long Text Area field on these objects.